# how can I find relative path for android.jar?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing some hotcoding thing, and I need to use android.jar in the process. However I have to manually add *android.jar* to **javassist** (a bytecode manipulation tool) classpool, but I dont want to use the absolute path of *android.jar* like now,

```
pool.insertClassPath("/Users/xinmei/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-
26/android.jar")
```

but I dont know how to get the relative path of it, can anyone give me some hint? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that I use copied from one of my projects:

```
public static String getPathName() {
    String fullPath = "";
    int endOfPath = 0;
    try {
        fullPath = new File(JOTI_App.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).toString();
        endOfPath = fullPath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return fullPath.substring(0, endOfPath);
}
```

Comment: My fault, the website editing tools messed up my code and I didn't check. I will edit my response.

Comment: thank you, btw I'm working on a groovy project, it's actually a plugin, does this matter?

Comment: And I'm not actually using any contents that's in the jar, I just need to add the path of the jar to javassist classPool

Comment: This should return the path of the named class (in this case "JOTI_App") so you can do with it whatever you want.

Comment: This is where I dont quite understand... How is this relate to the Jar file I want? and as it's known android.jar is a system jar, in which class am I gonna search it for?